# Start Mailchimp automated campaign after products shipped

Tags: magento-1.7, event-observer, shipment

how can I start an automated Mailchimp campaign after shipping products?

Comment: Also iterested in this, however the question will probably be closed as offtopic (

Comment: I hope this question would not be closed. It is a question of how to trigger the start of the campaign. The Trigger information is only available at Magento.

Answer (score 1):

Why not listen to the event `sales_order_shipment_save_after`. This event will give you the shipment object that you can work with. I am not sure what exactly you need to check but this event should give you enough information, but be careful as this will be fired on all saves and not just on create.